# How to disable multiwindow icon

Tags: multi-window

I have an old Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 tablet (GT-N8010), Jelly Bean 4.1.2.

Since the last firmware update, a multiwindow icon appeared in the lower right corner.  Its purpose is to switch the current app from fullscreen to windowed.  I don't use this feature, and the icon is right over the virtual keyboard -- very annoying.  How can I disable it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Samsung Galaxy Tab, the MultiWindow function is part of the Display Settings. Most likely similar in your device.

Settings > Display > General > Multi window

Disable by unchecking the feature.

Comment: I believe your solution is valid for the phone version of Jelly Bean 4.1.2.  Looks like the tablet version offers no way of disabling this feature.